# Fragments Layout inside ViewPager which inside another ViewPager not showen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My Activity Layout like this, 
Activity contains ViewPager1 that contains two fragments (Fragment1 and Fragment2) , Fragment1 contains ViewPager2 ,ViewPager2 contains 3 Fragments
the problems is these 3 Fragments Layout not shown even they exist on ViewPager.
I'm sure they added to ViewPager Adapter because when I debug it I can see them on ViewPager's Adapter

```
public class ViewPager1Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
private String[] titles;

public ViewPager1Adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.context = context;
    this.fragments = fragments;
    titles = new String[2];
    titles[0] = context.getString(R.string.fragment1);
    titles[1] = context.getString(R.string.fragment2);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return fragments.get(position);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}
```

}

ViewPager2 Adapter is same like ViewPager1

```
fragments.add(fragment21);
fragments.add(fragment22);
fragments.add(fragment23);
viewPager2Adapter = new ViewPager2Adapter(getActivity(),
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
vp2.setAdapter(viewPager2Adapter);
```

the problem is Fragment21 , Fragment22 and Fragment23 Layout is not shown?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update below line:

```
ViewPager1Adapter viewPager1Adapter = new viewPager1Adapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

**Reason:** You are calling wrong ViewPagerAdapter.

Also you should update your constructor of adapter, because you are having **2 string** for **title** so you should add **third string** for **third fragment**.

```
public ViewPager1Adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.context = context;
    this.fragments = fragments;
    titles = new String[3];
    titles[0] = context.getString(R.string.fragment1);
    titles[1] = context.getString(R.string.fragment2);
    titles[2] = context.getString(R.string.fragment3);
}
```

Hope this will help you.